# Is the complex space $\mathbb C\times \mathbb C$ a field?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, field-theory, vector-fields

Is the complex space $\mathbb C\times \mathbb C$ a field?
If not, which axiom that defines field doesn't hold?

Comment: How do you define addition and multiplication in $\mathbb C^2$?

Answer (score 4):

Presume you are performing addition and multiplication component-wise, i.e.

$$(x_1, y_1)+(x_2, y_2)=(x_1+y_1, x_2+y_2)$$
$$(x_1, y_1)(x_2, y_2)=(x_1y_1, x_2y_2)$$

In that case, the role of multiplicative unity ("one") is played by $(1,1)$:

$$(1,1)(x,y)=(1x, 1y)=(x,y)$$

and the role of additive unity ("zero") is played by $(0,0)$:

$$(0,0)+(x,y)=(0+x, 0+y)=(x,y)$$

However, look at the element $(1,0)$. It is *not* zero, but it hasn't got a multiplicative inverse, because there is no pair $(x,y)$ such that $(1,0)(x,y)=(1,1)$ - simply because $0y=0\ne 1$ for every $y$.

So, $\mathbb C\times\mathbb C$ is not a field because there are non-zero elements which don't have a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Would be interesting whether there is a definition of multiplication such that we get the Quaternions.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts I would cite your comment to John Hughes' answer below: "Isn't this (almost) trivial?". Now you need a bijection of $\mathbb C\times\mathbb C$ to quaternions - take $(x+iy, z+it)\mapsto x+iy+jz+kt$... and use it to define multiplication on $\mathbb C\times\mathbb C$ from the multiplication on the quaternions - as a result creating a structure of a *skew field* on $\mathbb C\times\mathbb C$...

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts $\mathbb C\times\mathbb C$ is tessarines.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @StinkingBishop's answer, the reason it starts with "Presume you are adding..." is this:

The cardinality of $\Bbb C \times \Bbb C$ is the same as that of $\Bbb R$, i.e., there exists some bijection $f$ from the first to the second, with inverse I'll call $g$ to save typing. If you define
$$
(a,b) \oplus (c, d) = g\left( f(a, b) + f(c, d) \right)
$$
and
$$
(a,b) \odot (c, d) = g\left( f(a, b) \cdot f(c, d) \right)
$$

then $\Bbb C \times \Bbb C$ actually *is* a field with the addition and multiplication operations $\oplus$ and $\odot$.

The broader implication of this contrived example is that it generally doesn't make sense to ask "Is such-and-such a set actually a field?" without specifying the operations you're considering.

There *are* special cases, however, where an intermediate kind of question makes sense. You can ask "Is there a multiplication operation $\otimes: S^2 \times S^2 \to S^2$ on the 2-sphere that makes the 2-sphere into a group, and in which $\otimes$ is a differentiable function?" In this case, you haven't specified what the operation is, but you have put some restriction on it. (Answer: it turns out that there's no such "multiplication", but it's not all that easy to prove.)

Comment: Isn't this (almost) trivial? These objects are isomorphic, hence no big deal.  Basically all you need is *some* bijection and knowing that $|\mathbb C^2|=|\mathbb R|$ (which means there exists some bijection).

Comment: It's completely trivial (like most mathematics) if you already know it. From OP's question, I'm guessing it's a new idea for them, and therefore deserves a little explanation. People who know and already understand what I've said don't ask "is C x C a field?" :)

Comment: Longer answer: I regard MSE as a source of fun puzzles and an opportunity to hone my teaching/explanation skills, and to try to discern the right level at which to answer a question (since that's part of what I do every day for my job). I found that "this is trivial" is almost never the right answer for me to give, but your experience may, of course, be different.

Comment: If the result is supposed to be a complex (vector) space as indicated by the question, then you'll have some trouble finding such a mapping.

Comment: I believe you and I are reading the question differently.

Answer (score 1):

**John Hughes**, I see what you mean. You are basically **re-writing** the elements of the set $\mathbb R$ using the elements of the set  $\mathbb C\times \mathbb C$ (which is possible as they have the same cardinality). Then you multiply and add the new elements just as if they still were in $\mathbb R$. This clearly makes $\mathbb C\times \mathbb C$ a field with respect to new fancy operations.

But I am confident **Karen** was meaning exactly what **Stinking Bishop** assumed. If I were an instructor who plans to include this in homework, I would necessarily mention that point.